# What do I need to setup my own Paymaster?

Tags: ethers.js, hardhat, account-abstraction, paymaster

I am trying to setup my own `Paymaster` contract to sponsor transaction on behalf of other users but I am really lost on what is the right approach.

Do I have to deploy my own `Entrypoint` smart contract or can I use the already existing ones in different blockchains?

After deploying the `AccountFactory` for account abstraction and after deploying the `Paymaster` pointing to an `Entrypoint` (assuming it is the correct one): how can I build a simple `UserOperation` (let's say the transfer of a token) for testing using `ethers` and `hardhat`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the existing `Entrypoint` contract no need to deploy it again , you can do it if you want to .
Here is the userOps object just create your `Smart Account` from the `AccountFactory` and pass the function signature in the `callData` field.
`[{ callData:"" , callGasLimit: 1000000, initCode: "0x", maxFeePerGas: 1000000016, maxPriorityFeePerGas: 1000000000, nonce: 18446744073709551616, paymasterAndData: "0x", preVerificationGas: 21000, sender: "", //Smart contract wallet address signature:"", signed userOps signature verificationGasLimit: 150000 }]`